# Not seeing header or property in Camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following Camel context XML.  I set a header named MediaType.  But, when I set a breakpoint in RenamerProcessor I don't see the header (I've also tried using setProperty with the same results.  Being very new to Camel, I've found several examples that make it seem like the below should work.

What is wrong?

```html
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="file://c:/CamelTVInput" />
        <camel:setHeader headerName="MediaType">
            <camel:constant>T</camel:constant>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:to uri="file://c:/CamelReadyToRename" />
    </camel:route>

    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="file://c:/CamelReadyToRename?move=//c:/CamelBackup" />
        <camel:process ref="RenamerProcessor" />
        <camel:to uri="file://c:/CamelOutput" />
    </camel:route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot transfer headers using files. eg when you write to a file, then its only the message body that is written as the file content.

But this is component specific if headers is part of the protocol, eg JMS, HTTP support headers.

If you want to keep files then use something else, Camel has some internal components like seda / direct.